# XGBoost (R Interface) throwing "label set cannot be empty" error

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to use the XGBoost model to perform a multi-class classification over 40 classes.

The code is as follows:

```
xgb_params = list(colsample_bytree= 0.7,
                  subsample = 0.7,
                  eta = 0.05,
                  objective= 'multi:softmax',
                  max_depth= 5,
                  min_child_weight= 1,
                  eval_metric= "mlogloss", num_class = categoryclassnos,
                  nthread=4)

fit.xgb = xgb.train(params = xgb_params,
                    data = dtrain,
                    nrounds = 500,
                    watchlist = list(train = dtrain, test=dtest),
                    print_every_n = 50)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Check failed: (info.labels.size()) != (0) label set cannot be empty

I have reproduced the dataset and the R script [here](https://github.com/abhishekkant/healthcarequeryclassifier).

Any help/ pointers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: In your code what does `trainlabelsfactored <- as.integer(train$primarydeptt) - 1` return

Comment: This returns an integer in the range [0,max] based on the factor values. XGBoost requires this range (starting from 0) for label.

Comment: Continuing to explore this... As an attempt, I added label value in dtest parameter. The error went away... I still don't get the logic as there is unlikely to be a label tag available for test data set while predicting..

Comment: When creating the xgb.DMatrix (dtrain, dtest), specify the `label` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

In python I needed to set the `label` param in  `dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train,label=y_train,feature_names=cfg_col_X)`

PS I was going to comment but missing rep points.

Answer (score 1):

To `train` a model you need two things, your training data(a matrix of variables and observations) and your labels (the known classification of each observation in the training data). Perhaps the last column in your data is actually the label? If so you will to vertically split your `dtrain` so that parameter `data=` all columns but the last, and a parameter `label=` just the last column.

Once you have the model, you can use it to `predict` on data that doesn’t have labels and the output will be the labels.